# What is the difference between non-blocking I/O and Asynchronous I/O in Java?

Tags: asynchronous, io, java-7, nonblocking, java-6

Before Java 7 there was non-blocking I/O .

In Java 7 the functionalities of Asynchronous I/O is introduced which does operations with a different thread without blocking the current thread.

How it is different , If non-blocking I/O is not implementing this , then how it is non-blocking , if it is using existing thread ?

Comment: Could you give an example of a class that is not NIO, but Asynchronous IO?

Comment: That's what my questions is ?

Comment: It is? You can have things like asynchronous servlets, which are non blocking, but they use a container's own background thread, not the selector model of the "standard" non-blocking IO.